# Embeds and paths

Tags: expressionengine

My code is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="3" dynamic="on" category="{category_id}" }
{embed="blog/feeds" my_rss="{blog_rss}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Inside blog/feeds I've got this:

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser url="{embed:my_rss}" itempath="/feed/entry" cache_refresh="60" limit="3" }  
<li>
<h3><a href="{path="blog/blog_item"}">{title}</a></h3>
<time datetime="2011-01-20T06:20:00-00:00">{published format="%l, %j %F %Y at %G:%i"}</time>
<p><a href="{author/uri}">{author/name}</a></p>
</li>
{/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```

The {path=blog/blog_item} is not taking me to the content page of that specific entry.

In blog_item I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" dynamic="on" category="{embed:category}"}
{embed="blog/feed_individual" my_rss="{blog_rss}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

and in blog/feed_individual I have the article:

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser url="{embed:my_rss}" itempath="/feed/entry" cache_refresh="60" limit="1"}
<article>
<header>
<h1>{title}</h1>
<time datetime="2011-01-20T06:20:00-00:00">{published format="%l, %j %F %Y at %G:%i"}</time>
<a href="{author/uri}" target="_blank">{author/name}</a>
</header>
{content}
</article>
{/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want `{path=blog/blog_item}` to go to `/blog/blog_item/{entry_id}`? `{entry_id}` being that of the current channel entry (and not related at all to what you're displaying with the FeedParser plugin)?

If so, just pass it to the embed:

```
{embed="blog/feeds" my_rss="{blog_rss}" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

Then in your embed, use:

```
<h3><a href="{path="blog/blog_item/{embed:entry_id}"}">{title}</a></h3>
```